# Why this code got "unreachable statement" error?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, unreachable-code

I have the following method :

```
  char getChar(int I)
  {
    if (I<65+26) return (char)(I);

    switch (I)
    {
      case 91 : return '?';break;
      case 92 : return '#';break;
      default : return ' ';
    }
  }
```

Why does it get "unreachable statement" error ?

Comment: And where exactly (which line) is this error marked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you can't `break` after you have already `return`ed. `return` means "exit the method". `break` means "exit the block".

So if you have:

```
return '?'; break;
```

then the `break` can never be reached.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't need a `break` statement after a `return`, since control has already left the structure (even the entire method) by way of the `return`:

```
switch (I)
{
  case 91 : return '?';
  case 92 : return '#';
  default : return ' ';
}
```

Anything after a `return` would never be reached.